# Pig Latin - Extracting fields meeting two different filter criteria from chararray line and grouping in a bag

Tags: apache-pig

I am new to Pig Latin.
I want to extract all lines that match a filter criteria (have a word "line_token" ) from log files and then from these matching lines extract  two different fields meeting two  separate field match criteria . Since the lines aren't structured well I am loading them as  a char array. 
When I try to run the following code - I get an error 
"Invalid resource schema: bag schema must have tuple as its field"
I have tried to perform an explicit cast to a tuple but that does not work

```
input_lines = LOAD '/inputdir/' AS ( line:chararray);

filtered_lines = FILTER input_lines BY (line MATCHES  '.*line_token1.*' );

tokenized_lines = FOREACH filtered_lines GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(line)) AS tok_line;

my_wordbag = FOREACH tokenized_lines {
     word1 = FILTER tok_line BY ( $0 MATCHES  '.*word_token1.*'  ) ;
     word2 = FILTER tok_line BY ( $0 MATCHES  '.*word_token1.*' ) ;
     GENERATE word1 , word2 as my_tuple ;
  -- I also tried --> GENERATE (word1 , word2) as my_tuple ;
    }

dump my_wordbag;
```

I suppose I am taking a very wrong approach.
Please note - my logs aren't structured well - so I cant mend the way I load 
Post loading and initial filtering for lines of interest ( which is straightforward) - I guess I need to do something different rather than tokenize line and iterate through fields trying to find fields.
Or maybe I should use joins ?

Also if I know the structure of line beforehand well as all text fields, then will loading it differently ( not as a chararray) make it an easier problem ?

For now I made a compromise - I added a extra filter clause in my original - line filter and settled for picking just one field from line. When I get back to it I will try with joins and post that code ... - here's my working code that gets me a useful output - but not all that I want.

```
-- read input lines from poorly structured log
input_lines = LOAD '/log-in-dir-in-hdfs' AS ( line:chararray) ;

-- Filter for line filter criteria and date interested in passed as arg
filtered_lines = FILTER input_lines BY (
       ( line MATCHES  '.*line_filter1*' )
       AND ( line MATCHES '.*line_filter2.*' )
       AND ( line MATCHES '.*$forDate.*' )
       ) ;

-- Tokenize every line
tok_lines = FOREACH filtered_lines
        GENERATE TOKENIZE(line) AS tok_line;

-- Pick up specific field frm tokenized line based on column filter criteria
fnames =   FOREACH tok_lines  {
        fname = FILTER tok_line BY ( $0 MATCHES  '.*field_selection.*' ) ;
        GENERATE FLATTEN(fname) as nnfname;
        }
-- Count occurances of that field and store it with field name 
-- My original intent is to store another field name as well 
-- I will do that once I figure how to put both of them in a tuple 
flgroup    = FOREACH fnames
         GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE((chararray)$0)) as cfname;
grpfnames  = group flgroup by cfname;
readcounts = FOREACH grpfnames GENERATE COUNT(flgroup), group ;
STORE readcounts INTO '/out-dir-in-hdfs';
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, after the FLATTEN operation, you have single line (tok_line) in each row and you want to extract 2 words from each line. REGEX_EXTRACT will help you achieve this. I'm not a REGEX expert so will leave writing the REGEX part up to you.

```
data = FOREACH tokenized_lines 
          GENERATE 
              REGEX_EXTRACT(tok_line, <first word regex goes here>) as firstWord,
              REGEX_EXTRACT(tok_line, <second word regex goes here>) as secondWord;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Gaurav - thanks a lot. This however wont solve my problem - as filter allows me to extract tokens I need...my problem is to group those two fields in a single bag - when I try to do that - I get an error - "Invalid resource schema: bag schema must have tuple as its field" or some other error based on how I try to force fit two fields in a bag, tuple or map using a cast or something silly of that kind

Comment: okay, did you try using TOTUPLE function? You need to pass fields to this function to create TUPLE out of those fields. e.g. TOTUPLE(field1, field2, field3).

Comment: That sounds useful - will try and keep you posted - Thanks !! :-)

Comment: Great. I would love to help you again. If my answer has solved your question, please mark it answered. This helps to identify questions which are answered vs not answered, and help me gain more points too :)

Answer (score 0):

You must refer to the alias, not the column.

So:

```
word1 = FILTER tokenized_lines BY ( $0 MATCHES  '.*word_token1.*'  ) ;
```

word1 and word2 are going to be aliases as well, not columns.

How do you need the output to look like?

Comment: Michal, that isn't what I need.  I do not want to filter the outer bag - tokenized_lines - that's a set of lines - using FOREACH I am already inspecting each of its element - I want to filter individual lines. And to answer your question, my output is two columns - ( two words that I am interested in - for every matching row)